# how to fix unresolved reference lifecycleScope?

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, build.gradle, kotlin-coroutines

Trying to build a simple example that uses kotlin coroutines in an activity:

```
   lifecycleScope.launch {
             val result = httpGet("http://hmkcode-api.appspot.com/rest/api/hello/Android")
              textView.setText(result)
   }
```

Can't get rid of error "unresolved reference lifecycleScope"

Relevant part of gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'



dependencies {

implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.2'
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.3.2'
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-rx2:1.3.2"

def androidArchVersion = '1.1.1'
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel:$androidArchVersion"
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:livedata:$androidArchVersion"
annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:$androidArchVersion"
testImplementation "android.arch.core:core-testing:$androidArchVersion"
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:$androidArchVersion"
}

kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '1.8'
    apiVersion = '1.3'
    languageVersion = '1.3'
}
```

}

Answer (score 28, accepted):

As per the [Lifecycle KTX documentation](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/ktx#lifecycle), you must include the `lifecycle-runtime-ktx` artifact if you want Coroutine specific extensions.

Note that `lifecycle-runtime-ktx` was only introduced in [Lifecycle 2.2.0](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle#2.2.0), so you'll need to [Migrate to AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate), then upgrade to Lifecycle `2.2.0` if you want to use that functionality.

Answer (score 8):

Late response here but I also faced this issue and finally managed to resolve it by changing the inherited Android `Activity` to an `AppCompatActivity`.

Comment: What if we are using `Hilt` in our Activity?