# Kotlin cant change button properties

Tags: android, xml, api, kotlin

I have a problem with changing the properties of a button in Kotlin. That is only in one function, it works fine in all others. It is weird because I can change the properties of a TextView in that function.
Here is the function:

```kotlin
override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
    val body = Klaxon().parse<API_result>(response.body!!.string())

    //setting these textView texts is no problem
    findViewById<TextView>(R.id.windSpeed).text = (body?.wind?.speed?.times(3.6)).toString() + " km/h"
    findViewById<TextView>(R.id.temperature).text = body?.main?.temp.toString() + " C"
    findViewById<TextView>(R.id.airPressure).text = body?.main?.pressure.toString() + " hPa"

    //changing button text is not working and crashes the app
    findViewById<Button>(R.id.fillOutForm).text = "Test"
}
```

Here is the whole file:

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var fusedLocationProviderClient: FusedLocationProviderClient
    private val client = OkHttpClient()
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)

        fetchLocation()
    }

    private fun fetchLocation(){
        val task = fusedLocationProviderClient.lastLocation
        if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION), 101)
            return
        }
        task.addOnSuccessListener {
            if(it != null){
                apiRequest(it.latitude, it.longitude)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun apiRequest(latitude: Double, longitude: Double){
        var url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=" + latitude + "&lon=" + longitude + "&appid=...&units=metric&lang=en";
        val request = Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .build()

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback{
            override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
                return
            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
                //code from above
            }
        })
    }
}

data class API_result(
    val main: main?,
    val wind: wind?
)

data class main(
    val temp: Double?,
    val pressure: Int?
)

data class wind(
    val speed: Double?
)
```

Before the app crashes, the button text gets updated correctly. If I remove the "button-line", the app works perfectly fine. I really don't know why that happens.
 It seems like only just TextViews are working in this funciton, because I just also tested it with Password and Email (which are also Texts) and a Switch. It worked in non of these cases.
I also recognised that I can access the xml element (e.g. the button) in that function without any problem, but I just cant set the properties of it.
For example, I can do this

```
findViewById<TextView>(R.id.someText).text = findViewById<Button>(R.id.someButton).text
```

but not this

```
findViewById<Button>(R.id.someButton).text = "exampleText"
```

Stacktrace:
[image: StackTrace]

I hope you can help me! Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Can you include the stack trace?

Comment: @gidds I have added it to the question

Comment: Can you show the code surrounding your `client.newCall()` call? What thread is it called from? Also, please don't post pictures of code/stack traces. Copy-paste the text so it is easier to see and can be searched.

Comment: Made the changes. If I paste the stacktrace into the codefield, it is not formatted.

Comment: This exception is caused when one is trying to update the UI from a background thread. Its quite strange to see that the problem is only for Button. Can you try to print the `Thread` name?

Comment: @akhilnair The problem is not only for button. I tried with different xml elements like a switch or the passwort or email text. It didn't work for them as well. So it only works for the basic TextView element...

Comment: Also: it is possible to access the element. For example, I can set the text of a textView equal to the text of an button without problems. I just can't set the buttons text...

Comment: @akhilnair how can I access the thread?

Comment: Print -> Thread.currentThread().getName():

Comment: Also can you please show where you call apiRequest?

Comment: @NitinJain I called it just after the line of code that doesnt work and it prints out the same thing like the stacktrace (see in the question): FATAL EXCEPTION: OkHttp Dispatcher.

Comment: @NitinJain I added the whole code to the question

Comment: @philale Did you try to print the Thread name?

Comment: @akhilnair yes, it was the same as in the stacktrace. FATAL EXCEPTION: OkHttp Dispatcher. I printed the thread just one line after the button line that is not working.

Comment: @akhilnair I also added the whole file. Maybe that helps

Comment: @philale Can you please print it before the button line ? And also before setting TextViews. This would be really helpful and interesting. Thanks

Comment: @akhilnair In both cases it prints: OkHttp https://api.openweathermap.org/...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the issue here is that you are accessing the UI objects from a non UI thread and this is causing the issue. Accessing UI Element from a non UI Thread causes **undefined behavior**.

> If you try to modify or even reference a UI object in a thread other than the main thread, the result can be exceptions, silent failures, crashes, and other undefined misbehavior.

You can read more about it [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/threads.html#references)

To fix this problem you need to access the UI objects from a UI thread as below. Also its not good to do `findViewById<TextView>(R.id.someText)` inside the `onResponse` as you are sure that the UI objects are always there. Instead initialize them inside the `onCreate` and access the reference variable everywhere.

```
lifecycleScope.launch {
        withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
            textView.text = "sometext"
            button.text = "sometext"
            //and so on
        }
    }
```

if you don't have coroutines in your project

```
runOnUiThread(Runnable { 
        textView.text = "sometext"
            button.text = "sometext"
            //and so on
    })
```

There is also a similar question and answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44890807/setting-text-on-textview-from-background-thread-anomaly)

Comment: And where should I put that in my code?

Comment: @philale Inside the `onResponse`.

Comment: lifecycleScope, withContext and Dispatchers is red. Do i need to define them?

Comment: @philale You need the corresponding dependencies. Just search it you will get it easily.

Comment: @philale implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.4.2" and  implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.2.0"

Comment: It is still red. I also cleaned the project but it didnt change.

Comment: @philale I guess you need to migrate your project to androidx first to have `lifecycle` scope.

Comment: Thank you! It worked with the other version in your answer!

Comment: @philale You should also try to get the first version of the answer running. Its the latest way of doing things. Below links would help you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60744043/how-to-fix-unresolved-reference-lifecyclescope
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines

Comment: I am not able to migrate to androidx, because it then says: "No Usages Found in the Project"